# Expandable ListView does not expanding

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a ExpandleListview with some TextViews and images.
After cliked i want to showTextView as child and hide another TextView in GroupView. Unfortunatly the list is displaying correctly but after clicked on item it does not expanding at all, event when I set OnGroupClickListener and try to debug it, the breakpoint does not trigger.

XML

```
<<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/notificationItem"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15sp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/notificationLogo"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:clickable="false"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="20sp"
        android:paddingLeft="10sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/notificationLogo"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/headerContent">

        <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/date"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/eventName"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/shortDescription"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fullDescription"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/downButton"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerContent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

ADAPTER CLASS

```
public class NotificationAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ViewHolder viewHolder;
    final Typeface typeface;
    List<MuseumNotification> notificationList;

    public NotificationAdapter(Context context, List<MuseumNotification>notificationList){
        mContext = context;
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),"fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
        this.notificationList =notificationList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return notificationList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return notificationList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return notificationList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(viewHolder==null)
            viewHolder =new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification_item,parent,false);

        viewHolder.notificationTitle=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventName);
        viewHolder.shortDescription=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.shortDescription);
        viewHolder.image_url=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.notificationLogo);
       viewHolder.notificationTitle.setText(notificationList.get(groupPosition).getTitle());
        viewHolder.shortDescription.setText(notificationList.get(groupPosition).getText());
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load("www.logo.png")
                .fitCenter()
                .into(viewHolder.image_url);
        viewHolder.navDown=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.downButton);
        viewHolder.navDown.setTypeface(typeface);
        viewHolder.navDown.setText(R.string.navDown);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification_item,parent,false);
        viewHolder.description=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.fullDescription);
        viewHolder.description.setText(notificationList.get(groupPosition).getText());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }
    private class ViewHolder{
        private TextView notificationTitle,description,shortDescription;
        private ImageView image_url;
        private Button navDown;
    }
}
```

EDIT: SOLVED: in group Item i have a clickable element (button). It should be unfocusable ( android:focusable="false" in XML)

Answer (score 0):

From the code which  you have mentioned ,I think you have not defined the `HashMap<>()` in your code .You need to define the HashMap in which you have stored the 'group_title' as the `key` and 'child title' as the `value`.Replace the code in the  `getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)` method by accessing a particular value of  the hashmap using the desired `groupPosition`(key).

For eg-
if you make a HashMap as-
`HashMap<>(MuseumNotification, String) hm;`
Then in the  `getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)`method write the following code

```
  return this.hm.get(this.notificationList.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosition);
```

Here notificationList is the `List` which you have defined in your code .This will give you the desired child for that particular `groupPosition`..

**Your code is returning the `Group`(Object) in your `getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)` and there you want a `Child`(Object)**

Answer (score 0):

**samarth kejriwal** your answear does not solve the problem however when i try to open item programicly in onCreate method its expanding correcly (by `expandleListView.expandGroup(position);`) I tried to `expandleListView.setOnItemClickListener` but its not work as well. I can scroll my list, only when I clicked on it nothing happened.